# Handly keypress on smart tv browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, samsung-smart-tv

I have developed restaurant ordering application that kitchen has a tv to monitor orders and when job ready need to press for example 1 to completed order but on samsung smart tv browser keypress is not fire , any solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can we see your code please?

Comment: @kapetanios: Simple test         $(document).keypress(function (e) {
            alert('Key');alert(e.which)});

Comment: So you are binding a keypress event handler to the entire page? why dont you create a `<input type='button' id='button1'/>` and then bind a `click()` event on it? eg `$("#button1").click(function({ alert(); });`

Comment: @kapetanios: They are using numeric key pad to press button

Comment: ok is the numeric keypad on screen or is it a physical device?

Comment: USB Keypad (physical)

Comment: Ok. Well first thing to check is if jQuery has been referenced since `keypress()` is a jQuery function not plain javasacript (i noticed you didnt add it as a tag so not sure).

Comment: Everything is working fine on pc or tablet , The issue is  only on Samsung Web Browser

Comment: if thats the case, then you may have to check with the provider of the samsung web browser or manufacturer of the TV. Sounds like a browser bug

Comment: @kapetanios : Thank you.

Comment: Samsung smart tv key codes are different from other smart tv and from normal keyboard, if you need any help regarding those let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For capture onkeydown event in Samsung browser you need to set focus to the some object which have this handler, for example to body:

```
window.onload = function()
{
      document.body.focus();
}
window.onkeydown = function(event)
{
      alert(event.keyCode);
}
```

Important to know - Samsung intercepts alert() and not shows it in popup, so, you will not see them. Instead of this, you can write your own handler:

```
function alert(s)
{
       document.getElementById('alert-block').innerHTML = s;
}
```